# finding if one string ("AB") is subset of another ("ABCD")?

Tags: c++, string, subset, substring

i had my midterm today. this was the first question. i could not solve this.
the exact requirement is as follows :
we have to determine if a string , lets say , "DA" is subset of another, "ABCD". the number of letters is crucial, for exmaple "DAD" is not a subset of "ABCD". because "D" is repeated twice whereas in the parent string "D" occurs once. also it can be assumed that that no. of letters of parent string is always equal to or greater than the other.

i thought a lot about this. my approach towards this was that i will compare the characters of the to-be-found substring with the parent string. if a match is found i will store its index in a third array. so in the end i will have the arrays of characters of the parent array which matched characters from the other array.this is how far i have been able to get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char array[] = "ABCD";
char array1[] = "AB";

int size = strlen(array);
int size1 = strlen(array1);

int temp[size];
int no = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< size1; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j< size; j++)
                {
                if  (array1[i]==array[j])
                        {
                        for(int k = 0; k<size ; k++)
                                {
                                if (temp[k] != j)
                                        {
                                        temp[no] = j;
                                        no++;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
cout<<endl<<temp[i]<<" ";
return 0;
}
```

kindly help in solving this and do tel me if you have another approach to this.
also, are arrays or a string a better approach to this problem.
i am writing in c++
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*(I recently used this as a quiz for my students but we're using Groovy and Java.)*

A simple aproach: create a copy of the string (`"ABCD"`) and *strike* matched letters so that they won't match again, for example after matching a "D" and "A", the copy would be `"_BC_"` and it would not match another "D".

Answer (score 0):

You can also count the number of occurrences of each letter in each string and make sure the count of each letter in the second string is less than or equal to the count of each letter in the first string. This might be better in the case where you want to compare multiple potential substrings to a single collection of letters (e.g. comparing all the words in the dictionary to the current letters in Boggle).

This code will do that. It has the primary limitation that it only works with strings containing the 26 capital letters in the English alphabet. But it gets the idea across.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void stringToArray(char *theString, int *countArray) {
    int stringLength = strlen(theString);
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        countArray[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {
        countArray[theString[i] - 'A']++;
    }
}

bool arrayIsSubset(int *superCount, int *subCount) {
    //returns true if subCount is a subset of superCount
    bool isSubset = true;
    for (int i=0; i<26 && isSubset; i++) {
        isSubset = subCount[i] <= superCount[i];
    }
    return isSubset;
}

int main()
{
    char array[] = "ABCD";
    char array1[] = "AB";
    char array2[] = "ABB";

    int letterCount[26], letterCount1[26], letterCount2[26];

    stringToArray(array, letterCount);
    stringToArray(array1, letterCount1);
    stringToArray(array2, letterCount2);

    cout << "array1 is " << (arrayIsSubset(letterCount, letterCount1) ? "" : "not ") << "a subset" << endl;
    cout << "array2 is " << (arrayIsSubset(letterCount, letterCount2) ? "" : "not ") << "a subset" << endl;
}
```

produces:

```
array1 is a subset
array2 is not a subset
```